# Load balancing of internet traffic from two ISPs using a linux router

Tags: linux

a)  write down the steps required to configure load balancing of internet traffic from two ISPs using a linux router.

b) how would you show that the router is load balancing?

Comment: This is *NOT* a site to get your home work done.

Comment: Ok wolfgangz.....js b eazy

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [article](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) or install shorewall and read [this manual](http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html).